# Calculate GMT local time in c#

Tags: c#, timezone

I have time table in GMT time zone and i need to calculate the local time .
For example:
I have the element:
`<option value="35" selected="selected" title="(GMT-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)">(GMT-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)</option>`

i need to calculate the local time but i can't use FindSystemTimeZoneById or ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId as the time zone value and display string can't be found in GMT.
for example

```
var timeZoneConvert = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(DateTime.UtcNow, "GMT Standard Time");
```

my question is, how can i convert the date i have to UTC terms (replace string will not help) ?

Thanks

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking.  First you ask how to convert from GMT to local time, but then you say you want to convert to UTC terms.  UTC and GMT are synonymous.  And by "local time", do you mean the time zone selected?  What is `35`? Do you have the corresponding `.Id` (which would be "Eastern Standard Time")?  Also, `"GMT Standard Time"` is the time zone for London, having both GMT and BST for daylight savings - you probably don't want that.  What *exactly* do you want to do?  What is your input, and what is your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use not display name for time zone ID but standart name 
`var timeZoneConvert = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(DateTime.UtcNow, "Eastern Standard Time");`

Comment: Keep in mind that the standard name is localized, and even in English it is sometimes quite different than the ID.